# angular - safely get reference of lazy loaded DOM Element

Tags: angular, dom, rxjs

I have a template section which is to be in the DOM only when the corresponding object exists. Furthermore I want to grab the form reference and attach a fromEvent('change') Observable to it.

Since the data arrives potentially after the ngAfterViewInit, there won't be a reference to get.

View

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async">
    <form id="form" #form></form>
</div>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('form') form;

ngOnInit(){
    this.user$ = this.someService.getUser() // returns Observable<User>
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    fromEvent(form || this.form,'change')...
}
```

I've also tried to move it to the callback of the observable like

```
   ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.user$ = this.someService.getUser().pipe(map(res => {
            const form = document.getElementById('form')
            fromEvent(form || this.form,'change')...
            return res
        }))
    }
```

Please **don't** suggest any solutions involving setTimeout()

Comment: you mean it it not getting updated to dom?

Comment: well the dom element i need the reference from obviously is not in the DOM yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use

```
@ViewChild('form') form;
```

which basically says "define an instance variable `form` within the Component and set its value to whatever DOM element is identified by `#form`.

As soon as the element identified by `#form` is created, Angular sets the value of the instance variable `form`.

The point is that in your `ngAfterViewInit` you say

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    fromEvent(form || this.form,'change')...
}
```

which says that you want to set a variable `form` visible only within `ngAfterViewInit` method with the value of an element whose id is `form`.

That element probably does not exists yet when `ngAfterViewInit` runs and you do not really know when it will be created. By the way, you are also creating a second variable `form` visible only within `ngAfterViewInit` to hold the same thing that should be held by `this.form`, i.e. the Component instance variable.

What you can consider is to remove the `@ViewChild('form') form;` code as well as the `ngAfterViewInit` logic and just add an event `formChanged` to the html element such as

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async">
    <form id="form" (changed)="formChanged($event)"></form>
</div>
```

and then implement a method `formChaged(event)` to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use (changed) instead of hooking directly into the DOM - definitely better than going outside Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Picci is correct to state that for the code you have posted, you should simply be using the (changed) Angular event on the form tag rather than directly hooking into the DOM. However, if you do need to get a reference to a late-loaded component as you have stated, you need to do something like:

```
formInitialised: bool = false;

// Implement AfterViewChecked to run this each time the view
// changes - note this will run many times, so you need to keep
// track of whether you have done whatever form initialisation
// you need.
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // Check if form is now defined
    if (this.form && !this.formInitialised) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with this.form
        this.formInitialised = true;
    }
    // If the form has disappeared from the page, update
    // our flag to say so.
    if (!this.form && this.formInitialised) this.formInitialised = false;
}
```